# why static varible in functions and templates

Tags: c++

I have learned something basic about `static` key

1. The object becomes globalized in the program (i.e it is accessible from everywhere) with just use of scope operator `::`.
2. A static object is constructed at runtime on a stack.
3. No matter where you put or declare the static object, the runtime machine knows its presence by copying its instances in all units available.

   For example,

> ```
> void Data::NonStaticMethod
> {
>    static Data _data;
>    _data.Method();
> }
> ```

4. `static` is indispensable in templates, though I don't know why it is used in code like this,

> ```
> template<typename T>
> struct A
> {
>    static int i;
> }
> ```

Could you tell me why `static` in the above code and what I can do to remove that `static` key without changing the design of the program or affecting the output result?

Comment: All of your bullet points are wrong. Where did you "learn" that?

Comment: I google it here and there.

Comment: `static` ensures the life-time from first access to end of run-time. From where it can be accessed directly (by its name) depends on scope (and has nothing to do with `static`). Hence, `_data` survives every `return` from `Data::NonStaticMethod()` but can never be accessed from outside. (This is acutally used as an effective method to guard global instances.)

Comment: Thank you Scheff, that is an excellent answer. Could you explain to me the template's use of static variables ?

Comment: Thank you melpomene, could you repair my thinks about static keyword?

Comment: `static` is *entirely unrelated* to templates. You would use it in a class template for the same reasons you would use it in a class, and in a function template for the same reasons you would use it in a function